# Links on mobile site moving from their real position

Tags: android, hyperlink, meta-tags, mobile-website

I have a page with links.

It's supposed to recognize a mobile device and change a little. When I navigate to it on a mobile device (including an emulator) nothing happens when I click links. However, when I click a bit to the left it registers a click and navigates to the link (see image below for clicking on link 2)

[image: Clicking link 2]

Anyone ever heard of something like this happening?

Tagged android because issue was seen and tested on anorid specifically, not sure if true for other devices.

**`*`EDIT`*`**

Removing the following has fixed the issue:

```
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1'>
```

I don't like this solution, wasn't the `viewport` tag supposed to help mobile view?

Comment: Do you have a sample we could see? What specific Android versions/devices are you seeing the problem?

Comment: @Offbeatmammal not at the moment, I don't really want to keep it out there. Android version didn't seem to matter, I don't remember which we checked (I'm pretty sure it was at least 2 different versions)